# Loadbalancing with reserved IPs in Google Container Engine

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I want to host a website (simple nginx+php-fpm) on Google Container Engine. I built a replication controller that controls the nginx and php-fpm pod. I also built a service that can expose the site.

How do I link my service to a public (and reserved) IP Address so that the webserver sees the client IP addresses?

I tried creating an ingress. It provides the client IP through an extra http header. Unfortunately ingress does not support reserved IPs yet:

```
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: example.org
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: example-web
         servicePort: 80
        path: /
```

I also tried creating a service with a reserved IP. This gives me a public IP address but I think the client IP is lost:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: 'example-web'
spec:
  selector:
    app: example-web
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
  loadBalancerIP: "10.10.10.10"
  type: LoadBalancer
```

I would setup the HTTP Loadbalancer manually, but I didn't find a way to configure a cluster IP as a backend for the loadbalancer.

This seems like a very basic use case to me and stands in the way of using container engine in production. What am I missing? Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are running in google-container-engine you could set up a [Compute Engine HTTP Load Balancer](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/) for your static IP. The [Target proxy](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/target-proxies) will add `X-Forwarded-` headers for you.

Set up your kubernetes service with type [NodePort](http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/docs/user-guide/services.html#type-nodeport) and add a `nodePort` field. This way `nodePort` is accessible via kubernetes-proxy on every nodes IP address regardless of where the pod is running:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
 name: 'example-web'
spec:
 selector:
   app: example-web
 ports:
   - nodePort: 30080
     port: 80
     targetPort: 80
 type: NodePort
```

Create a [backend service](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/backend-service) with HTTP health check on port 30080 for your instance group (nodes).

Comment: Was just informed that the ingress controller will allocate static ips before it leaves beta.